# How to populate a text field of a different page on button click from a text field value on another page using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textfield

There is a field for enter users email address in my home page and a button. Once user enters the email and hit the button it should redirect to the register page and automatically populate register form's email field value form that value. I know how to do this in JQuery but the issue is sending values from one page to another...

Home page:

```
<input type="email" id="valbox"  class="text-box form-control" style="max-width: 200px;"placeholder="Enter Your Email Id" required>
<button type="submit" id="butval" class="btn btn-default rounded subscribe px-5 ml-4 float-left">SUBMIT</button>
```

Register Page:

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control " name="email" value="" required autocomplete="email">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Home page should pass the value to a `session` as follows:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <input type="email" id="valbox"  class="text-box form-control" style="max-width: 200px;" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id" required>
          <button type="submit" id="butval" class="btn btn-default rounded subscribe px-5 ml-4 float-left">SUBMIT</button>
     </body>
     <script>
          $(function() {
               $('#butval').on('click', function(){
                    let text = $('#valbox').val();
                    if(!text){
                         alert("Please enter your email")
                    }else{
                         sessionStorage.setItem("email", text);
                         window.location.replace("login.html");
                    }
               })
          });
     </script>
</html>
```

Then, your Register page would retrieve it and set it to the value of the email input:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control " name="email" value="" required autocomplete="email">
     </body>
     <script>
          $(function() {
               $('#email').val(sessionStorage.getItem("email"));
          });
     </script>
</html>
```